# put only elements into a list with a certian number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`S_id` is the sales ID and `i_id` is the sold itemid. I would like to use all unique i_ids to find all purchases that have interacted with i_id. I also implemented this in the loop. What I would like that I only want to add something to the list when the `s_id` has more of a 1 item.

How do I do that so that I only add the purchases to the list if it contains more than one item?

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'s_id': [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5],
     'i_id': [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df)


numers_i = df.i_id.unique().tolist()

for i in numers_i:
  buyers = df[df.i_id.eq(i)].s_id.unique()
  df_new = df[df.s_id.isin(buyers)]
  list_new = df_new.groupby("s_id")['i_id'].apply(list).tolist()
  print(list_new)
```

Output

```
[[1], [1, 2, 3], [1], [4, 1, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 5]]
[[4, 1, 2]]
[[3, 5]]
```

But what I want

```
[[REMOVED], [1, 2, 3], [REMOVED], [4, 1, 2]] 
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 5]]
[[4, 1, 2]]
[[3, 5]]
```

`[REMOVED]` means that the element does not exist, I only wrote for a better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different approach with two `groupby`s. One for getting the items in an `s_id` and the other for grouping the purchases happened along with particular `i_id`s.

Firstly, get the mapping of `s_id` to list of `i_id`

```
map_dict = df.groupby('s_id')['i_id'].apply(list).to_dict()

map_dict
{1: [1], 2: [1, 2, 3], 3: [1], 4: [4, 1, 2], 5: [3, 5]}
```

Then grouping by `i_id` to create list of list of items if length of "list of items" is greater than 1

```
def func(df):
    return ([items for items in df['s_id'].map(map_dict) if len(items) > 1])

df.groupby('i_id').apply(lambda x: func(x))

i_id
1    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2]]
2    [[1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2]]
3    [[1, 2, 3], [3, 5]]   
4    [[4, 1, 2]]           
5    [[3, 5]]              
dtype: object
```

Compared the timing, this approach (`6.71 ms ± 91 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`) seems to be faster than approach in question (`12.3 ms ± 201 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a filter to list_new after its creation:

Instead of this:

```
  list_new = df_new.groupby("s_id")['i_id'].apply(list).tolist()
  print(list_new)
```

Try this:

```
  list_new = df_new.groupby("s_id")['i_id'].apply(list).tolist()
  list_new=[i for i in list_new if len(i)>1]
  print(list_new)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 2]]
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 5]]
[[4, 1, 2]]
[[3, 5]]
```